# Adding a key/value pair once I have recursively searched a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I have searched a nested dict for certain keys, I have succeeded in being able to locate the keys I am looking for, but I am not sure how I can now add a key/value pair to the location the key I am looking for is. Is there a way to tell python to append the data entry to the location it is currently looking at?

Code:

```
import os
import json
import shutil
import re
import fileinput
from collections import OrderedDict

#Finds and lists the folders that have been provided
d='.'
folders = list(filter (lambda x: os.path.isdir(os.path.join(d, x)), os.listdir(d)))
print("Folders found: ")
print(folders)
print("\n")


def processModelFolder(inFolder):

#Creating the file names 
    fileName = os.path.join(d, inFolder, inFolder + ".mdl")
    fileNameTwo = os.path.join(d, inFolder, inFolder + ".vg2.json")
    fileNameThree = os.path.join(d, inFolder, inFolder + "APPENDED.vg2.json")
#copying the json file so the new copy can be appended
    shutil.copyfile(fileNameTwo, fileNameThree)
#assigning IDs and properties to search for in the mdl file
    IDs = ["7f034e5c-24df-4145-bab8-601f49b43b50"]
    Properties = ["IDSU_FX[0]"]
#Basic check to see if IDs and Properties are valid
    for i in IDs:
             if len(i) != 36:
                print("ID may not have been valid and might not return the results you expect, check to ensure the characters are correct: ")
                print(i)
                print("\n")
    if len(IDs) == 0:
        print("No IDs were given!")
    elif len(Properties) == 0:
        print("No Properties were given!")
#Reads code untill an ID is found           
    else:
        with open(fileName , "r") as in_file:

            IDCO = None
            for n, line in enumerate(in_file, 1):
                if line.startswith('IDCO_IDENTIFICATION'):
                    #Checks if the second part of each line is a ID tag in IDs
                    if line.split('"')[1] in IDs:
                        #If ID found it is stored as IDCO
                        IDCO = line.split('"')[1]
                    else:
                        if IDCO:
                            pass
                            IDCO = None
                #Checks if the first part of each line is a Prop in Propterties
                elif IDCO and line.split(' ')[0] in Properties:
                    print('Found! ID:{} Prop:{} Value: {}'.format(IDCO, line.split('=')[0][:-1], line.split('=')[1][:-1]))
                    print("\n")
                    #Stores the property name and value
                    name = str(line.split(' ')[0])
                    value = str(line.split(' ')[2])
                    #creates the entry to be appended to the dict
                    #json file editing        
                    with open(fileNameThree , "r+") as json_data:
                        python_obj = json.load(json_data)
                    #calling recursive search
                    get_recursively(python_obj, IDCO, name, value)




    with open(fileNameThree , "w") as json_data:
        json.dump(python_obj, json_data, indent = 1)



        print('Processed {} lines in file: {}'.format(n , fileName))

def get_recursively(search_dict, IDCO, name, value):
    """
    Takes a dict with nested lists and dicts,
    and searches all dicts for a key of the field
    provided, when key "id" is found it checks to,
    see if its value is the current IDCO tag, if so it appends the new data.
    """
    fields_found = []

    for key, value in search_dict.iteritems():

        if key == "id":
            if value == IDCO:
                print("FOUND IDCO IN JSON: " + value +"\n")
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            results = get_recursively(value, IDCO, name, value)
            for result in results:
                x = 1
        elif isinstance(value, list): 
            for item in value:
                if isinstance(item, dict):
                    more_results = get_recursively(item, IDCO, name, value)
                    for another_result in more_results:
                        x=1
    return fields_found



for modelFolder in folders:
    processModelFolder(modelFolder)
```

In short, once it finds a key/id value pair that I want, can I tell it to append name/value to that location directly and then continue?

nested dict:

```
{
  "id": "79cb20b0-02be-42c7-9b45-96407c888dc2",
  "tenantId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "name": "2-stufiges Stirnradgetriebe",
  "description": null,
  "visibility": "None",
  "method": "IDM_CALCULATE_GEAR_COUPLED",
  "created": "2018-10-16T10:25:20.874Z",
  "createdBy": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "lastModified": "2018-10-16T10:25:28.226Z",
  "lastModifiedBy": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "client": "STRING_BEARINX_ONLINE",
  "project": {
    "id": "10c37dcc-0e4e-4c4d-a6d6-12cf65cceaf9",
    "name": "proj 2",
    "isBookmarked": false
  },
  "rootObject": {
    "id": "6ff0010c-00fe-485b-b695-4ddd6aca4dcd",
    "type": "IDO_GEAR",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "1dd94d1a-e52d-40b3-a82b-6db02a8fbbab",
        "type": "IDO_SYSTEM_LOADCASE",
        "children": [],
        "childList": "SYSTEMLOADCASE",
        "properties": [
          {
            "name": "IDCO_IDENTIFICATION",
            "value": "1dd94d1a-e52d-40b3-a82b-6db02a8fbbab"
          },
          {
            "name": "IDCO_DESIGNATION",
            "value": "Lastfall 1"
          },
          {
            "name": "IDSLC_TIME_PORTION",
            "value": 100
          },
          {
            "name": "IDSLC_DISTANCE_PORTION",
            "value": 100
          },
          {
            "name": "IDSLC_OPERATING_TIME_IN_HOURS",
            "value": 1
          },
          {
            "name": "IDSLC_OPERATING_TIME_IN_SECONDS",
            "value": 3600
          },
          {
            "name": "IDSLC_OPERATING_REVOLUTIONS",
            "value": 1
          },
          {
            "name": "IDSLC_OPERATING_DISTANCE",
            "value": 1
          },
          {
            "name": "IDSLC_ACCELERATION",
            "value": 9.81
          },
          {
            "name": "IDSLC_EPSILON_X",
            "value": 0
          },
          {
            "name": "IDSLC_EPSILON_Y",
            "value": 0
          },
          {
            "name": "IDSLC_EPSILON_Z",
            "value": 0
          },
          {
            "name": "IDSLC_CALCULATION_WITH_OWN_WEIGHT",
            "value": "CO_CALCULATION_WITHOUT_OWN_WEIGHT"
          },
          {
            "name": "IDSLC_CALCULATION_WITH_TEMPERATURE",
            "value": "CO_CALCULATION_WITH_TEMPERATURE"
          },
          {
            "name": "IDSLC_FLAG_FOR_LOADCASE_CALCULATION",
            "value": "LB_CALCULATE_LOADCASE"
          },
          {
            "name": "IDSLC_STATUS_OF_LOADCASE_CALCULATION",
            "value": false
          }
        ],
        "position": 1,
        "order": 1,
        "support_vector": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 0
        },
        "u_axis_vector": {
          "x": 1,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 0
        },
        "w_axis_vector": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 1
        },
        "role": "_none_"
      },
      {
        "id": "ab7fbf37-17bb-4e60-a543-634571a0fd73",
        "type": "IDO_SHAFT_SYSTEM",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "7f034e5c-24df-4145-bab8-601f49b43b50",
            "type": "IDO_RADIAL_ROLLER_BEARING",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "0b3e695b-6028-43af-874d-4826ab60dd3f",
                "type": "IDO_RADIAL_BEARING_INNER_RING",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "id": "330aa09d-60fb-40d7-a190-64264b3d44b7",
                    "type": "IDO_LOADCONTAINER",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "id": "03036040-fc1a-4e52-8a69-d658e18a8d4a",
                        "type": "IDO_DISPLACEMENT",
                        "children": [],
                        "childList": "DISPLACEMENT",
                        "properties": [
                          {
                            "name": "IDCO_IDENTIFICATION",
                            "value": "03036040-fc1a-4e52-8a69-d658e18a8d4a"
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "IDCO_DESIGNATION",
                            "value": "Displacement 1"
                          }
                        ],
                        "position": 1,
                        "order": 1,
                        "support_vector": {
                          "x": -201.3,
                          "y": 0,
                          "z": -229.8
                        },
                        "u_axis_vector": {
                          "x": 1,
                          "y": 0,
                          "z": 0
                        },
                        "w_axis_vector": {
                          "x": 0,
                          "y": 0,
                          "z": 1
                        },
                        "shaftSystemId": "ab7fbf37-17bb-4e60-a543-634571a0fd73",
                        "role": "_none_"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "485f5bf4-fb97-415b-8b42-b46e9be080da",
                        "type": "IDO_CUMULATED_LOAD",
                        "children": [],
                        "childList": "CUMULATEDLOAD",
                        "properties": [
                          {
                            "name": "IDCO_IDENTIFICATION",
                            "value": "485f5bf4-fb97-415b-8b42-b46e9be080da"
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "IDCO_DESIGNATION",
                            "value": "Cumulated load 1"
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "IDCO_X",
                            "value": 0
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "IDCO_Y",
                            "value": 0
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "IDCO_Z",
                            "value": 0
                          }
                        ],
                        "position": 2,
                        "order": 1,
                        "support_vector": {
                          "x": -201.3,
                          "y": 0,
                          "z": -229.8
                        },
                        "u_axis_vector": {
                          "x": 1,
                          "y": 0,
                          "z": 0
                        },
                        "w_axis_vector": {
                          "x": 0,
                          "y": 0,
                          "z": 1
                        },
                        "shaftSystemId": "ab7fbf37-17bb-4e60-a543-634571a0fd73",
                        "role": "_none_"
                      }
                    ],
                    "childList": "LOADCONTAINER",
                    "properties": [
                      {
                        "name": "IDCO_IDENTIFICATION",
                        "value": "330aa09d-60fb-40d7-a190-64264b3d44b7"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "IDCO_DESIGNATION",
                        "value": "Load container 1"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "IDLC_LOAD_DISPLACEMENT_COMBINATION",
                        "value": "LOAD_MOMENT"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "IDLC_TYPE_OF_MOVEMENT",
                        "value": "LB_ROTATING"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "IDLC_NUMBER_OF_ARRAY_ELEMENTS",
                        "value": 20
                      }
                    ],
                    "position": 1,
                    "order": 1,
                    "support_vector": {
                      "x": -201.3,
                      "y": 0,
                      "z": -229.8
                    },
                    "u_axis_vector": {
                      "x": 1,
                      "y": 0,
                      "z": 0
                    },
                    "w_axis_vector": {
                      "x": 0,
                      "y": 0,
                      "z": 1
                    },
                    "shaftSystemId": "ab7fbf37-17bb-4e60-a543-634571a0fd73",
                    "role": "_none_"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": "3258d217-e6e4-4a5c-8677-ae1fca26f21e",
                    "type": "IDO_RACEWAY",
                    "children": [],
                    "childList": "RACEWAY",
                    "properties": [
                      {
                        "name": "IDCO_IDENTIFICATION",
                        "value": "3258d217-e6e4-4a5c-8677-ae1fca26f21e"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "IDCO_DESIGNATION",
                        "value": "Raceway 1"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "IDRCW_UPPER_DEVIATION_RACEWAY_DIAMETER",
                        "value": 0
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "IDRCW_LOWER_DEVIATION_RACEWAY_DIAMETER",
                        "value": 0
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "IDRCW_PROFILE_OFFSET",
                        "value": 0
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "IDRCW_PROFILE_ANGLE",
                        "value": 0
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "IDRCW_PROFILE_CURVATURE_RADIUS",
                        "value": 0
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "IDRCW_PROFILE_CENTER_POINT_OFFSET",
                        "value": 0
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "IDRCW_PROFILE_NUMBER_OF_WAVES",
                        "value": 0
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "IDRCW_PROFILE_AMPLITUDE",
                        "value": 0
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "IDRCW_PROFILE_POSITION_OF_FIRST_WAVE",
                        "value": 0
                      },
```

Comment: To add `(key, value)` to a dictionary `dic`: `dic[key] = value`.

Comment: I just added the first 300 lines of the nested dicts, the problem I am having is the the dict that contains the id I want changes often, and I need a way of appending to the location the id is found at, if I try these solutions it adds the entry to the first level only

Comment: You are saying that you have a dictionary and inside that dictionary you have `(key, value)` pairs where the value is *also* a dictionary? Therefore you want `dic[key][new_key] = new_value` where `(new_key, new_value)` is the new pair you want to add to that nested dictionary identified by `key` on the first level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Bug

First of all, replace the `value` variable's name by something else, because you have a `value` variable as the method argument and another `value` variable with the same name when iterating over the dictionary:

```py
for key, value in search_dict.iteritems(): # <-- REPLACE value TO SOMETHING ELSE LIKE val
```

Otherwise you will have bugs, because the `value` from the dictionary is the new value which you will insert. But if you iterate like `for key, val in` then you can actually use the outer `value` variable.

### Adding The Value Pair

It seems `id` is a key inside your `search_dict`, but reading your JSON file your `search_dict` may have several nested lists like `properties` and/or `children`, so it depends on where you want to add the new pair.

#### If you want to add it to the same dictionary where your `id` is:

```py
if key == "id":
    if value == IDCO:
        print("FOUND IDCO IN JSON: " + value +"\n")
        search_dict[name] = value
```

Result:

```
{
    "id": "3258d217-e6e4-4a5c-8677-ae1fca26f21e",
    "type": "IDO_RACEWAY",
    "children": [],
    "childList": "RACEWAY",
    "<new name>": "<new value>",
    "properties": [
      {
        "name": "IDCO_IDENTIFICATION",
        "value": "3258d217-e6e4-4a5c-8677-ae1fca26f21e"
      },
```

#### If you want to add it to the `children` or `properties` *list* inside the dictionary where `id` is:

```py
if key == "id":
    if value == IDCO:
        print("FOUND IDCO IN JSON: " + value +"\n")
        if search_dict.has_key("properties"): # you can swap "properties" to "children", depends on your use case
            search_dict["properties"].append({"name": name, "value": value}) # a new dictionary with 'name' and 'value' keys
```

Result:

```
{
    "id": "3258d217-e6e4-4a5c-8677-ae1fca26f21e",
    "type": "IDO_RACEWAY",
    "children": [],
    "childList": "RACEWAY",
    "properties": [
      {
        "name": "IDCO_IDENTIFICATION",
        "value": "3258d217-e6e4-4a5c-8677-ae1fca26f21e"
      },
      {
        "name": "<new name>",
        "value": "<new value>"
      },
```

Comment: Thank you, but when it adds the value it adds this `{
        "name": "IDSU_FX[0]", 
        "value": "0.01\n"
       }` and I don't know why

Comment: Please check the values of your `name` and `value` variables in your `processModelFolder` function when you assign to them. You can do `print(name)` and `print(value)` and check the console.

Comment: I double checked them, they print as `name: IDSU_FX[0]
value: 0.01`.